# How to return to a different loop python

Tags: python, loops, blackjack

I am making a black jack game and I want to make it so that you can try again, but to do that you would have to access a loop that was already broken out of, how can I replay an old loop, here is the code (The highlighted loop is the one I am reffering to.):

```
import random

playerIn = True
dealerIn = True

name = input("Please type you name: ")

# deck of cards.
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
       'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
Typecard = ['Of Hearts', 'Of Spades', 'Of Clubs', 'Of Diamonds']
playerHand = []
dealerHand = []

# deal the cards
def dealCard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card)

#calculate the total of each hand
def total(turn):
     total = 0
     face = ['J', 'K', 'Q' ]
     for card in turn:
         if card in range(1, 11):
             total += card
         elif card in face:
             total += 10
         else:
             if total > 11:
                 total += 1
             else:
                total += 11
     return total


#Check winner
def revealDealerHand():
     if len (dealerHand) == 2:
         return dealerHand[0]
     elif len (dealerHand) > 2:
         return dealerHand[0], dealerHand[1]

#Game loop
for _ in range(2):
    dealCard(dealerHand)
    dealCard(playerHand)

***while playerIn or dealerIn:
    print(f"\nDealer has {revealDealerHand()} and X")
    print(f"\nYou have {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)}")
    if playerIn:
        stayOrHit = input("\nWould you like to stay or hit (type 1 for stay and 2 for hit): ")
    if total(dealerHand) > 16:
        dealerIn = False

    else:
        dealCard(dealerHand)
    
    if stayOrHit == "1":
        playerIn == False

    else:
        dealCard(playerHand)
    if total(playerHand) >= 21:
        break
    elif total(dealerHand) >= 21:
        break***

]
if total(playerHand) == 21:
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
    print(f"BLACKJAAACK! Nice one {name}")

elif total(dealerHand) == 21:
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
    print("BLACKJACK, Dealer wins you lose, HA!")

elif total(playerHand) > 21:
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
    print("You bust loser, Dealer wins.")

elif total(dealerHand) > 21:
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
    print(f"The dealer busts, You win {name}!")

elif 21 - total(dealerHand) < 21 - total(playerHand):
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
    print("Dealer Wins, loser.")

elif 21 - total(playerHand) < 21 - total(dealerHand):
    print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
print(f"You Win {name}!")
```

I tried to make it inside of another loop so that it would go all the way back but then I wouldn't let me break out of the original loop.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/about).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

playerIn = True
dealerIn = True

name = input("What is your name? ")

# Deck of cards.
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
cardTypes = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"]
cardInheritances = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

# Player's hand.
playerHand = []

# Dealer's hand.
dealerHand = []

# Deal the cards.
def deal():
    for i in range(2):
        playerHand.append(random.choice(deck))
        dealerHand.append(random.choice(deck))
        deck.remove(playerHand[i])
        deck.remove(dealerHand[i])

def sum(hand):
    total = 0
    for i in hand:
        total += i
    return total

# Player's turn.
def playerTurn():
    global playerIn
    while playerIn:
        print("Your hand: ", playerHand)
        print("Your total: ", sum(playerHand))
        if sum(playerHand) == 21:
            print("You got 21!")
            playerIn = False
        elif sum(playerHand) > 21:
            print("You busted!")
            playerIn = False
        else:
            hitOrStay = input("Would you like to hit or stay? ")
            if hitOrStay == "hit":
                playerHand.append(random.choice(deck))
                deck.remove(playerHand[-1])
            elif hitOrStay == "stay":
                playerIn = False
            else:
                print("Invalid input.")

# Dealer's turn.
def dealerTurn():
    global dealerIn
    while dealerIn:
        print("Dealer's hand: ", dealerHand)
        print("Dealer's total: ", sum(dealerHand))
        if sum(dealerHand) == 21:
            print("Dealer got 21!")
            dealerIn = False
        elif sum(dealerHand) > 21:
            print("Dealer busted!")
            dealerIn = False
        elif sum(dealerHand) < 17:
            dealerHand.append(random.choice(deck))
            deck.remove(dealerHand[-1])
        else:
            dealerIn = False

# Compare the hands.
def compareHands():
    if sum(playerHand) > sum(dealerHand):
        print("You win!")
    elif sum(playerHand) < sum(dealerHand):
        print("You lose!")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!")

# Play the game.
def play():
    deal()
    playerTurn()
    dealerTurn()
    compareHands()

# The game loop.
while True:
    play()
    playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    if playAgain == "yes":
        playerHand = []
        dealerHand = []
        playerIn = True
        dealerIn = True
    else:
        break
```

The usage of functions is quite useful when in a loop.
You should also reset the variables once a new game is called.

This is just a quick example, it is not entirely complete but it gets the point across.